# Importing a website into visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, silverlight, iis

Right now I have all the ASP.NET/Silverlight source code sitting on the IIS server and just set up VS2010. How would I take that code and create a project where I will be able to debug and test new code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local IIS Web Project :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckk1e6z4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If, after setting up your local project, you need to test/debug with the actual domain instead of "localhost" in the url, modify your hosts file.  Here are a couple of good readings on this....

http://www.codecurry.com/2009/04/using-separate-host-or-domain-names-for.html
http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2009/12/24/creating-local-development-domain-on-windows